# Retrieve / change Authentication Contact Info

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am creating Azure Active Directory users using Powershell & Azure AD Graph API ( I'm extending the schema with 1 field.)
i did not yet find how I could set the "Authentication email" to a specific value. (nor the other information like authentication phone, ...)
Is it possible to query this field & change the value for specific users by using the Azure AD Graph API?

Best regards,

Jens

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about setting secure auth settings (like those for Multi-Factor Authentication)?  AFAIK these are currently only supported through AAD PowerShell.  Exposing these settings is something we have in our backlog, but likely will be exposed only through Microsoft Graph.
Jens - can you provide a scenario for why you want to set these properties through your application?

Thanks,